# Как правильно прописать if?

Tags: c#, mysql

Хочу сделать проверку на количесвто, т.е больше или меньше.
К примеру - у меня в БД 5000, я ввожу в Textbox 5900 и он автоматом меняет на 5000. 
Вот как я паршу значение:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT `Acronal_470` FROM `Dispersii_svyazyshego`");
string name = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Потом записываю её в label7:

```
label7.Text = name.ToString();
```

И делаю if:

```
if (label7.Text > textBox1.Text)
                {

                }
```

Но он ругается(, что не так?

Comment: Ты сравниваешь строки а не их длину

Comment: @Duoxx т.е? Как мне сравнить? Я хочу сравнить значение в label, а не длину

Comment: `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse`

Comment: @Igor накидали бы ответ сразу)

Comment: @Igor Что-то не доходит как впихнуть int.parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int value_L7, value_TB1;
if (int.TryParse(label7.Text, out value_L7) && 
    int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value_TB1) && 
    value_L7 > value_TB1)
{
  // ...
}
```